# ¿Alguien podría mirar mi código?, quiero saber si es legible y si se podría refactorizar

Tags: javascript

Lo que tengo que hacer es lo siguiente:

> Realizar el algoritmo que permita ingresar los datos de una compra productos de la construcción, hasta que el cliente quiera:
>
> Tipo validad("arena";"cal";"cemento")
> Cantidad de bolsas,
> Precio por bolsa (más de cero ),
>
> Si compro más de 10 bolsas en total tenes 15% de descuento sobre el total a pagar.
> Si compro más de 30 bolsas en total tenes 25% de descuento sobre el total a pagar.
>
> a) El importe total a pagar , bruto sin descuento y...
> b) el importe total a pagar con descuento(solo si corresponde)
> d) Informar el tipo con mas cantidad de bolsas.
> f) El tipo mas caro

El código que hice es el siguiente:

```
function mostrar()

{
  var tipoProducto;
  var cantidadBolsas;
  var precioBolsas;
  var importeTotalBruto;
  var descuento;
  var acumuladorBolsasArena;
  var acumuladorBolsasCal;
  var acumuladorBolsasCemento;
  var respuesta;
  var banderaCaro;
  var tipoMasCaro;
  var tipoMayorBolsas;
  var importeTotalconDescuento;
  var acumuladorPrecioCal;
  var acumuladorPrecioCemento;
  var acumuladorPrecioArena;
  var precioBrutoCal;
  var precioBrutoArena;
  var precioBrutoCemento;
  var PrecioDescuentoArena;
  var PrecioDescuentoCal;
  var PrecioDescuentoCemento;
  var acumuladorDescuentoArena;
  var acumuladorDescuentoCal;
  var acumuladorDescuentoCemento;
  var precioBruto;
  

  respuesta=true;
  banderaCaro=true;
  descuento=0;
  acumuladorBolsasArena=0;
  acumuladorBolsasCal=0;
  acumuladorBolsasCemento=0;
  acumuladorTotalBolsas=0;
  acumuladorTotalPrecio=0;
  acumuladorPrecioArena=0;
  acumuladorPrecioCal=0;
  acumuladorPrecioCemento=0;
  acumuladorDescuentoArena=0;
  acumuladorDescuentoCal=0;
  acumuladorDescuentoCemento=0;

  while(respuesta==true)
  {

    tipoProducto=prompt("Ingrese un tipo de producto arena, cal , cemento");

    while(tipoProducto!="arena" && tipoProducto!="cal" && tipoProducto!="cemento")
    {
      tipoProducto=prompt("error ,Reingrese un tipo  valido de producto arena, cal , cemento");
    }

    cantidadBolsas=prompt("ingrese cantidad de bolsas");
    cantidadBolsas=parseInt(cantidadBolsas);

    while(cantidadBolsas<1 || isNaN(cantidadBolsas))
    {
        cantidadBolsas=prompt("error , reingrese cantidad de bolsas");
        cantidadBolsas=parseInt(cantidadBolsas);
    }

    precioBolsas=prompt("ingrese precio de bolsas");
    precioBolsas=parseInt(precioBolsas);

    while(precioBolsas<1 || isNaN(precioBolsas))
    {
      precioBolsas=prompt("error ,reingrese precio de bolsas");
      precioBolsas=parseInt(precioBolsas);
    }

      precioBruto=cantidadBolsas*precioBolsas;

    if(cantidadBolsas>30)
    {
      descuento=precioBolsas*0.25;
    }
    else
    {
      if(cantidadBolsas>10)
      {
        descuento=precioBolsas*0.15;
      }
      else
      {
        descuento=0;
      }
    }

 


    switch(tipoProducto)
    {
      case "arena": 
      acumuladorBolsasArena=acumuladorBolsasArena+cantidadBolsas;
       precioBrutoArena=precioBruto;
       acumuladorPrecioArena=acumuladorPrecioArena+precioBrutoArena;
       if(descuento!=0)
       { 
        PrecioDescuentoArena=precioBrutoArena-descuento;
        acumuladorDescuentoArena=acumuladorDescuentoArena+PrecioDescuentoArena;
       
       }
        break;
      case "cal": 
        acumuladorBolsasCal=acumuladorBolsasCal+cantidadBolsas;
        precioBrutoCal=precioBruto;
        acumuladorPrecioCal=acumuladorPrecioCal+precioBrutoCal;
        if(descuento!=0)
        { 
        PrecioDescuentoCal=precioBrutoCal-descuento;
        acumuladorDescuentoCal=+acumuladorDescuentoCal+PrecioDescuentoCal;
        }
        
        break;
      case "cemento":  
        acumuladorBolsasCemento=acumuladorBolsasCemento+cantidadBolsas;
        precioBrutoCemento=precioBruto;
        acumuladorPrecioCemento=acumuladorPrecioCemento+precioBrutoCemento;
        if(descuento!=0)
        { 
        PrecioDescuentoCemento=precioBrutoCemento-descuento;
        acumuladorDescuentoCemento=acumuladorDescuentoCemento+PrecioDescuentoCemento;
        }
      
        break;
    }



    respuesta=confirm("desea seguir?");

  }

    if(precioBruto>tipoMasCaro || banderaCaro==true)
    {
      tipoMasCaro=tipoProducto;
      banderaCaro==false;
    }


    importeTotalBruto=acumuladorPrecioArena+acumuladorPrecioCal+acumuladorPrecioCemento;
    
    importeTotalconDescuento=acumuladorDescuentoArena+acumuladorDescuentoCal+acumuladorDescuentoCemento;



    if(acumuladorBolsasArena>acumuladorBolsasCal && acumuladorBolsasCal>acumuladorBolsasCemento)
    {
      tipoMayorBolsas="arena";
    }
    else
    {
      if(acumuladorBolsasCal>acumuladorBolsasCemento && acumuladorBolsasCal>=acumuladorBolsasArena)
      {
        tipoMayorBolsas="cal";
      }
      else
      {
        tipoMayorBolsas="cemento";
      }
    }
    


    document.write("el importe total bruto sin descuento es "+importeTotalBruto+"<br>");
    document.write("el importe total con descuento es "+importeTotalconDescuento+"<br>");
    document.write("el tipo de producto con mayor cantidad de bolsas es "+tipoMayorBolsas+"<br>");
    document.write("el tipo de producto mas caro es "+tipoMasCaro+" <br>");
 

}
```

De lo que no estoy seguro es si mi código es legible o si es muy repetitivo, me ayudaría saber si hay una forma más optima de hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la duda?, te recomiendo leas [ask]

Comment: *no se poner el codigo por aca*. Basta con *copiar y pegar*, además, es de mucha utilidad leer [ask] y realizar el [tour].

Comment: Acabo de mirar tu código.

Comment: mi duda es ,si esta bien echo en cuanto a si es legible y si cumple con lo que me pide el enunciado

Comment: listo ya peque el codigo

Comment: Respecto a su cimple con el enunciado ¿has probado tu código?, colocar algunos casos de uso te daría contexto si entrega la salida esperada en cada caso.

Comment: claro que lo probe , y funciona , pero mi pregunta seria si hay una manera  mas  optima de hacerlo , siento que repito código demás o que mi lógica no esta del todo bien planteada

Comment: Para revisiones de codigo, existe un sitio dentro de la red que se llama code review....

Comment: Sí se puede simplificar, creando un arreglo de objetos para los productos, todos con las mismas propiedades. De esta forma evitas crear variables independientes para cada uno y, de paso, puedes agregar productos nuevos modificando solo un poco para validar.

Comment: para simplificarlo puedes utilizar arreglos u objetos tambien crear funciones para no repetir 3 veces cada validacion para cada producto...

Comment: Como puedes ver tienes una clase base, la podrias llamar Materia Prima, otro objeto generico lista en donde tienes una operacion base descuento.

Comment: muchas gracias , era lo que necesitaba saber ...

Answer (score 2):

podrias hacerlo asi que permite manejar mas productos y mas descuentos con solo modificar las varibales **descuentos** y **materiales** :

```
let materiales = {
    "arena": [{ "precio": 0, "cantidad": 0 }],
    "cal": [{ "precio": 0, "cantidad": 0 }],
    "cemento": [{ "precio": 0, "cantidad": 0 }]

};

let descuentos = {
    "10": 15,
    "30": 30
};
```

## ejemplo:

```js
// los materias 
    let materiales = {
        "arena": [{ "precio": 0, "cantidad": 0 }],
        "cal": [{ "precio": 0, "cantidad": 0 }],
        "cemento": [{ "precio": 0, "cantidad": 0 }]

    };


// descuentos
    let descuentos = {
        "10": 15,
        "30": 30
    };
    
    
// resultados 
    let resultado = {
        "bolsas": 0,
        "total": 0,
        "mas": [0, ""],
        "caro": [0, ""]
    };



 //valida materiales
    function validaMateriales(text) {
        let prom;
        while (true) {
            prom = prompt(text).toLowerCase();
            if (Object.keys(materiales).includes(prom)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return prom;
    }

    function descuento(num) {
        let des = 0;
        // obtenemos las llaves y ordenamos
        for (let x of Object.keys(descuentos).sort()) {
            // si el numero es mayor o igual
            // aplicamos el  descuento

            if (num >= parseInt(x)) {
                des = descuentos[x];
            }
        }
        return des;
    }

    function Moneda(num) {
        num = Number(num);
        return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-EN', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD', minimumFractionDigits: 2 })
            .format(num);
    }

    function validateNum(text) {
        let num = 0;

        while (true) {
            let prom = prompt(text);
            num = Number(prom);

            if (!isNaN(num) && num) {
                break;
            }
        }

        return num;
    }



    function main() {

        while (true) {

            let prom = validaMateriales("ingrese material?", materiales);

            if (prom) {
                materiales[prom][0]["cantidad"] = validateNum(`ingrese cantidad de bolsas ${prom}`);
                materiales[prom][0]["precio"] = validateNum(`ingrese precio de ${prom}`);
            };

            if (!confirm("desea seguir?")) break;

        }


        for (let x in materiales) {
            resultado["bolsas"] += materiales[x][0]["cantidad"];
            resultado["total"] += (materiales[x][0]["cantidad"] * materiales[x][0]["precio"]);

            if (resultado["mas"][0] < materiales[x][0]["cantidad"]) {
                resultado["mas"][0] = materiales[x][0]["cantidad"];
                resultado["mas"][1] = x;
            }

            if (resultado["caro"][0] < materiales[x][0]["precio"]) {
                resultado["caro"][0] = materiales[x][0]["precio"];
                resultado["caro"][1] = x;
            }
        }

        des = descuento(resultado["bolsas"]);
        total = Moneda(resultado["total"]);
        totalDescuento = Moneda(resultado["total"] - (resultado["total"] * ("0."+des)));

        document.write(`el importe total bruto sin descuento ${total}<br>`);
        document.write(`el descuento es del ${des}%<br>`);
        document.write(`el importe total con descuento es ${totalDescuento}<br>`);
        document.write(`el tipo de producto con mayor cantidad de bolsas es ${resultado["mas"][1]}<br>`);
        document.write(`el tipo de producto mas caro es ${resultado["caro"][1]} <br>`);

    }

    main();
```

Comment: bro uff me salvaste sos un crack sin palabras,te tomaste un re laburo te agradezco

Comment: @alexgomez si la respuesta te ayudo, no olvides marcarla saludos.